# Problem: qt-gtk-engine

Tags: 11.10, qt

I need to install this package in my Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric Ocelot. But, as I understand - this is obsolete now. But how can I install GTK+ engine for Qt?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the previous GTK+2 based theme engines have not been ported to use the GTK+3 API.  This also includes [gtk-qt-engine](http://code.google.com/p/gtk-qt-engine/updates/list) - it looks like development of this has dramatically slowed.

There are a few engines with some very good themes being developed.

For QT-based apps you should use `qt4-qtconfig` and select the GTK style to make QT apps look similar to GTK based apps.  Then apply some of the excellent themes around which your QT-based apps should inherit the GTK characteristics.

Below are a selection of some AskUbuntu! Q&A's that you might care to consult.

---

Linked Questions

1. [How can I theme my Qt app to resemble one written in Gtk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22316/how-can-i-theme-my-qt-app-to-resemble-one-written-in-gtk)
2. [What GTK+ 3 engines are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57510/what-gtk-3-engines-are-available/57513#57513)
3. [How do I change to a theme not listed in the Appearance screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61567/how-do-i-change-the-theme)
4. [Where to find great themes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11519/where-to-find-great-themes)