# Has anyone got the Mist engine to work on gtk3?

Tags: themes, gtk3, engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What GTK+ 3 engines are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57510/what-gtk-3-engines-are-available)

I've just upgraded my xubuntu installation to Precise and run into gtk3 theme problems - my theme based on the Mist engine doesn't work for gtk3 apps. There's a package gtk3-engines in the GNOME PPA that includes Mist, has anyone got this to work? It has a themes/Mist/gtk3.0 folder with a gtkrc file but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Even if someone just has an idea where I could find more help on this I'd be grateful (is there even any documentation on making themes in gtk3?)

Comment: Not so much a duplicate as a follow-up question. I installed the package mentioned but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Since you've been unable to make this work, this confirms that Mist has not yet been ported to Gtk3.  The only engines that have been ported are as described in that Q&A.  I'll close this now as a duplicate.